# How to filter a joined entity in JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have this query presented below and I'd like to retrieve only some tProducts filtered out by some property name (let's say which is active or not, a boolean), how can I do that?
Can somebody help?

```
        value = "SELECT DISTINCT(t) FROM Trfi t " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH t.trfiProductCollection tProducts " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH tProducts.productModel pModel " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH t.trfiPaymentCollection tPayment " +
            "WHERE t.sedId IN (:sessionIds) ",
        countQuery = "SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT t) FROM Trfi t " +
            "JOIN t.trfiProductCollection tProducts " +
            "JOIN tProducts.productModel pModel " +
            "JOIN pModel.provider provider " +
            "JOIN t.trfiPaymentCollection tPayment " +
            "WHERE t.sedId IN (:sessionIds) "
    )
    List<Trfi> getTrfiListBySessionsId(@Param("sessionIds") List<Integer> sessionIds);
```

Comment: did you try something like this "where tProducts.active = FALSE"?

Comment: tProducts is a list, I cannot access whatever property from it just like that...

Answer (score 1):

Does that not work for you?

```
    value = "SELECT DISTINCT(t) FROM Trfi t " +
        "LEFT JOIN FETCH t.trfiProductCollection tProducts " +
        "LEFT JOIN FETCH tProducts.productModel pModel " +
        "LEFT JOIN FETCH t.trfiPaymentCollection tPayment " +
        "WHERE t.sedId IN (:sessionIds) and tProducts.active = :active",
    countQuery = "SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT t) FROM Trfi t " +
        "JOIN t.trfiProductCollection tProducts " +
        "JOIN tProducts.productModel pModel " +
        "JOIN pModel.provider provider " +
        "JOIN t.trfiPaymentCollection tPayment " +
        "WHERE t.sedId IN (:sessionIds) and tProducts.active = :active"
)
List<Trfi> getTrfiListBySessionsId(@Param("sessionIds") List<Integer> sessionIds, @Param("sessionIds") boolean active);
```